# How to split long conditional expressions in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

Here is my conditional expression in `coffeescript`. How can I split it over multiple lines to make it more readable.

```
isWhat = (isAdd url) or (isUpdate url) or (isDelete url) or (isLockList url) or (isPasswordList url) or (isRemoteOpen url) or (isOpenRecord url)
```

Comment: can you show us the code for some of your `isAdd`, `isUpdate` etc. functions?

Comment: Well, I think it was a good edit. It is nice to be able to salvage a question.

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech there r brief function return true or false,and i dont want use if-else and switch to finish my work.

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech  i just want write this code  in a column，because it too long in a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In coffeescript you can split conditional expressions over multiple lines as long as you indent the continued expression one level so it knows to execute it as one expression.

It'll depend on your preference or style guide whether you put the `or` at the end of the line, or the start of the next line.

I would also suggest wrapping the function arguments in parenthesis, rather than the whole function. This makes it easier to read, yet still prevents coffeescript from executing the `or` before the function.

```
isWhat = isAdd(url) or 
  isUpdate(url) or 
  isDelete(url) or 
  isLockList(url) or 
  isPasswordList(url) or 
  isRemoteOpen(url) or 
  isOpenRecord(url)
```

Comment: Good answer....but it doesn't seem to work with the "or" at the start of the next line, only at the end of the line.  Also, this is just plain awkward -- it would be nice to line things up vertically instead of adding an un-intuitive indent.  Come on, Coffeescript -- you can do better!